# iOS Framework for integrating offline and online Apache Solr searches

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, apache, solr

I have a request to implement Apache Solr (version 4.0) into iOS app. I did a bit of research on what is Apache Solr, and it seems like good search engine. How can I implement Apache Solr searches into iOS App. Is there any framework for these purposes?
I need to do indexed offline and online search.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: If you need to ask this question in such way, you will fail - find a backup plan. This is not a joke or a critique, just a statement.

Comment: What solution did you find in the end?

Answer (score 1):

I found a good library that resolved my current needs:  S4LuceneLibrary
https://github.com/mikekppp/S4LuceneLibrary

which is based on: https://github.com/tcurdt/lucenekit/

and is dependent on: https://github.com/mikekppp/S4iOSLibraries

I am still in testing phase of it, but once I get more of it, I will update my answer.

The best way to understand this library is to go with java example from Lucene and try to find the same things in the lucenekit (the Objective-C version of lucene).

The things, I am missing in order to complete the task and what Apache Solr is offering is to have different types document parsers into text files. Lucene only parses text files.